# Get list of SQL_IDs between begin snapshot and end snapshot time in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, awr

I want to get the list of SQL_Id executed between a beginning snapshot and the end snapshot time in Oracle.
We can get the list from the AWR report but I need a SQL query which will return all the SQL IDs.
SQL Id is present in the V$SQL table but there isn't any column for snapshot time.

UI

[image]

Tried to get idea from the below queries-

```
select *  from V$SQL;
desc V$SQL;
SELECT * FROM dba_hist_snapshot;
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this could help you to connect SQL_ID with SNAP_ID

```sql
SELECT
    ids.SQL_ID, 
    snp.SNAP_ID, snp.STARTUP_TIME, snp.BEGIN_INTERVAL_TIME, snp.END_INTERVAL_TIME
FROM
     dba_hist_snapshot snp
Inner Join
    DBA_HIST_SQLSTAT ids ON(ids.SNAP_ID = snp.SNAP_ID)
```